# Randomize a string in C

Tags: c, algorithm, random

I'm trying to generate random permutations of an 80-character fixed string in C.  Much to my dismay, the system I'm working on lacks strfry().  What's the best way for me to generate a random permutation of this string?  Since this will be looped over approx. 100,000 times, performance is an issue.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Just use the Open Source GLIBC implementation, as found by [Google Code](http://www.google.com/codesearch/p?hl=en#WbTnQ5DcqbM/glibc-2.1.3/string/strfry.c&q=strfry).

```
char *
strfry (char *string)
{
  static int init;
  static struct random_data rdata;
  size_t len, i;

  if (!init)
    {
      static int state[8] = { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8 };
      rdata.state = NULL;
      __initstate_r (time ((time_t *) NULL), state, 8, &rdata);
      init = 1;
    }

  len = strlen (string);
  for (i = 0; i < len; ++i)
    {
      int32_t j;
      char c;

      __random_r (&rdata, &j);
      j %= len;

      c = string[i];
      string[i] = string[j];
      string[j] = c;
    }

  return string;
}
```

You might want to change the GLIBC specific data types to something more generic.

This code uses the [Fisher-Yates shuffle](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fisher-Yates_shuffle) which is actually quite easy to implement by yourself, and very efficient.

Comment: You might want to change the proprietary word there, else Stallman might go get you with his katana. A proper substitute might be GLIBC specific.

Comment: Konrad, you are a gentleman and a scholar!  I tried searching Google Code, but I was looking for things like 'randomize a string in c' instead of simply 'strfry'.  Thank you!

Comment: Am I the only one who thinks that creating and using a re-entrant random-number generator takes a beautiful algorithm and makes it ugly?

Comment: I'd like to mention that strfry() is my favorite name for a function. For a while, it was floorf(), but then I found strfry().

Answer (score 0):

create a 80-line array, put a character and a random number into each line of the array, then sort the array on the random numbers.

Rebuild string from sorted array.

Answer (score -2):

void gcry_randomize (unsigned char *buffer, size_t length, enum gcry_random_level level)

Fill buffer with length random bytes using a random quality as defined by level.

http://www.g10code.com/p-libgcrypt.html

Comment: Aside from being a proprietary function, which I'm afraid I didn't specify I'd like to avoid, this doesn't actually suit my purpose.  I'm trying to generate a random permutation of an existing string -- not a random string.  The character frequency is important.